# H-Bridge with highly inductive load

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, h-bridge, magnetics, electromagnetic

I am trying to understand the H-bridge, I have edited the circuit and followed the advice in this thread. Is this a good H-bridge design for excitation of the magnetic core which is highly inductive load?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are avoiding PNP transistors?

Comment: You need floating base drivers for the top transistors. Use e. It can translate from one potential to another.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a good H-bridge design for excitation of the magnetic core

As depicted, V2 and V3 are 0-5V with no current limiting.  This is impossible in reality; the two lower transistors would fail instantly.  The base has no intrinsic current-limiting feature; trying to push more voltage into it than it was designed for (0.7V for standard transistors, 1.4V for Darlingtons) will cause unlimited current to flow.

The two upper transistors are likely not even being turned "on", see below.

To use a transistor as a switch, realize that a TIP142's collector is "switched" or low-resistance to it's emitter only when there is enough base current flowing.  The base acts as a "valve" to allow this collector-emitter current to flow.  The ratio of base current to collector current is called the beta or gain of the transistor.  The [TIP142 Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tip142.pdf) is a Darlington type, so has very high gain; 500 at least.  Meaning, that in order for it to switch a 1A load, the base must have at least 1A/500 = 2mA.

Each base current is with respect to each *emitter* lead.

For the lower two transistors, this base current could be limited appropriately by adding a resistor to the base such that only >= 2mA will flow .  Easy, but what value resistor?

Consider that for a Darlington, the voltage drop between base and emitter is about 1.4V, so this is subtracted from the pulse supply of 5V to get 3.6V: that is what must be dropped by the base resistor.  3.6V/2mA = 1.8k or smaller.

Now consider the upper transistors; their bases cannot be driven from V2 and V3 *because those are referenced to ground, not the upper transistor emitters.*

If you put 1.8k resistors on each base, and drive each base-emitter junction independently, it will work a whole lot better.

The circuit could also be simplified by using PNP transistors on the top, as pulling those gates to ground (through base-current-limiting resistors) is how those are typically controlled.

Edit (good point Marla): Finally, consider that the pulse sources are ideal in simulation and the transistors are identical; this makes timings perfect.  But in the real world, the transistors won't be perfectly matched, so will have slight timing differences.  Trace shape and length introduce tiny parasitic inductances and capacitances also, which further alter timings.  The bottom line is, there is a good chance that one upper and lower transistor on the same side could be "on" at the same time, even just for a millionth of a second due to these delays.  This is termed "shoot-through" because both transistors are "on" and this directly connects the power rails and usually means the destruction of the transistors (along with noisy power transients which will probably upset the rest of the circuitry.)

The solution to shoot-through is to apply some dead-time (inactive time to both) gate pulses, such that a top and bottom (left or right) pair of transistors can never be "on" at the same time.

Given that this transistor's max turn-off delay is 4µs, that might be a good dead-time to incorporate.  If you pick a PNP transistor for the top pair, remember to check those delays and adjust according to whichever has the maximum delay.

Comment: And note that the TIP-142 is very slow because it's old and Darlington.  If you live somewhere that you can get them, power MOSFETs are a much better choice (but you still need to drive their gates appropriately).

Comment: Saw that in the datasheet... 4µs to turn off 40mA? Wow, didn't realize how slow these were.

Comment: @rdtsc. .  and don't forget to mention that dead time is needed between the gate pulses.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the issues pointed out by rdtsc, bipolar transistors in a H-bridge with an inductive load absolutely need a free-wheeling diode across each transistor. Otherwise, when they turn off, the kickback from your inductive load will fry them.

Using MOSFETs solves this issue, because you get a free body diode. This also solves most other issues like high saturation voltage, slow switching, very slow turn-off, cross-conduction, etc, provided the MOSFETs are properly driven.

Please don't stick a PMOS on top, a NMOS on the bottom and call it a day. That will cause a lot of cross-conduction. There are plenty of chips which, for a reasonable cost, will drive your FETs properly, add a bit of dead time, and even generate the extra voltage to drive the top NMOS with a charge pump.  Some also provide extra features like current measurement and limiting, etc. You can also get readymade H-bridges from pololu, robotshop, and similar outlets, probably for less money than the cost of the PCB plus parts.